# How to enable multi touch support for touchpad?

Tags: touchpad

I was using Manjaro and when I was using it, I was able to multi touch. Let me explain. When dragging and dropping, my touchpad wasn't enough for whole screen so I was just pressing with my one finger and then using my second finger to move the file. I can't do that on Ubuntu. I hope there is a feature for that.

my ubuntu version: 22.04

`sudo lsusb` output:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bc2:231a Seagate RSS LLC Expansion Portable
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 5986:9102 Acer, Inc BisonCam,NB Pro
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

my `sudo lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP DRAM Controller (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Management Engine (rev 30)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 30)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34b4 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron/Crucial Technology Device 5403 (rev 03)
```

I hope there is a solution like using `xinput` or something.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're using (1) some hardware details for your touchpad, such as the output of `sudo lsusb` or `sudo lspci`? With this, it will be much easier to answer your question in a meaningful way 